# I am new to Automation Testing, Using Python with Eclipse. I have followed installation steps properly But not able to see .py and .project

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

I am using Python with Eclipse for Automation Testing. I have followed installation steps properly, but I am not able to see `.py` and `.project`, it is showing External Libs, Forced builtins etc.

[image]

Comment: Have you already created a python script that should be available on that view?

Comment: NO... I just want to create script... But its not showing .project. Did you see the attachment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a python project in Eclipse, It looks the same way. you just right click on the Test Project and Create New Package and create python file and Start writing the code.

Note:- If you are using Linux, You can install Selenium by using pip install -U Selenium

Comment: How to implement page object model in Python with selenium.?